# In VBNet, how to get the control's TAG from the sender's object after drag and drop

Tags: vb.net, properties, controls, drag, drop

In VBNet (VS2022), how can one retrieve the control's tag from the sender's object? For example, I can retrieve the text from a label control being dropped on another label like so:

Private Sub Label1_DragDrop(sender As Object, e As DragEventArgs) Handles Label1.DragDrop

dim draggedText as string
' the dragged label text
draggedText = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text).ToString
end sub

So this basically gets like label4.text (if label4 was the control dragged). But how do we access label4.tag ?

I can programmatically set a global variable on the mouse down event prior to drag but I thought there has to be a direct way on accessing the control's property.
TIA.

Comment: Be handy if you updated your question with some actual code but...  Tag is a property of Control.  All windows controls like label, text box etc inherit that property.  You need to cast the sender object to a control (if it is in fact a control), then you will have access to the tag property.  Have a look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.dataobject.getdata?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) which has examples of testing the data object types

Comment: `dim tagContent = DirectCast(sender, Control).Tag.ToString()`